# How to replace brake lever from integrated shifter?

Tags: shifter, brake-levers

I had recently upgraded from grip shifter to thumb shifter. I have attached the new ST EF50 shifter for my Btwin RR 340vtt. Just today I broke the brake lever from the shifter. I don't want to replace the whole set. I just want to replace the brake lever. is it possible? I have some brake lever which may fit with that. Is that really possible? the brake lever cannot be welded as its an alloy. Do I have any options.

[image: This is the pic of broken brake lever of the shifter st ef50]

Comment: Plenty available for peanuts (almost) on ebay!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the answer to ST-EF50 in particular, but usually the lever blade (the part that broke here) is indeed able to be mechanically removed and reinstalled, given the willingness to go that deep with disassembly. However, Shimano doesn't sell replacement lever blades for many or any brake levers anymore, and definitely not the more entry level ones such as this. If you were able to replace it, it would tend to need to be an exact matching part; there's nothing like standardization for this. So that suggests that if you are able to replace it, it's going to be by way of a blade scavenged from another of the same unit. The good news is that ST-EF50 is one of if not the most populous flatbar such part from the last decade or so, so a lot of shops that keep broken shifters and derailers for cannibalization may have one in a bucket somewhere.

Comment: Given any reasonable hourly repair rate, the cost for disassembling, repairing, and reassembling the shifter is probably a lot more than just getting a complete replacement off eBay.

Comment: I have got some alhonga brake lever which can be replaced with tht but how can i detech the brack lever cuz there is a rivet screw . I dont know any thing about unscrewing those rivetS. If it was simply screw instead it would be very easy to replace those levers. The shimano ST EF50 brake levers are good but its not durablr

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's absolutely true. I usually assume it's implicit with this kind of answer that it would only make sense for the home hobbyist/tinkerer/cheapskate to undertake something like this.

Comment: @SyedMehfooz If it's riveted you're probably out of luck unless you want or need to make a more serious metalworking-y level project out of it. You're kinda getting into the territory here where it's technically conceivable to do all sorts of stuff, and in an extreme enough situation or just for fun it might make sense to try, but it stops being the sort of thing there are going to be known answers for.

Comment: I was unable to open the screw so replaced with an acera shifter.